# Anyway to get a Yup schema from an API?

Tags: serialization, yup

I use Yup validation and we use it both in backend and on the front end. I currently am using a npm library to share the schemas. This requires both the front and back ends to be updated with any schema change and redeployed. I'm wondering if there is any way to get a Yup schema from an API, so I only need to update the backend. Note, I'm not asking how to send the data to the backend to have it validated. I want to validate quickly on the front end, just get the appropriate schema from an API. The schema is large with a couple hundred fields and it has custom code for transforms and tests. This is a JavaScript/React/Node project.